# Creating Multipage PDF witth Headers and Footers iTextSharp

Tags: itext

Hello everyone and thanks for your help in advance.  I need to develop an application to generate a multipage PDF with iTextSharp.  Each page needs to have a header and footer.  Additionally, each page will have a variety of different objects including tables, paragraphs, and something similar to listitems (probably a cone column table).  I'm trying to find a tutorial to accomplish this.  At the heart of my confusion is how to determine when a break should happen and how to not overlay the footer if for example the table or paragraph is too long to fit on the page.  Any help would be appreciated.

I appreciate the response from Bruno and am intrigued with styling an HTML page, then rendering with iText, but I'm really struggling with how to actually do this on a real page.  Here is some sample HTML of the page I want to print:

```
<body>
<header class="onlyprint">
    <ul>
        <li>
            Dr. Who
        </li>
        <li>
            1234 Somewhere St.
        </li>
        <li>
            Anywhere, US  12345
        </li>
    </ul>
</header>
<div id="divmain" style="width:  760px;">

    <ul id="ulPatientDetails">
        <li>
            <label>Patient Name:</label>
            <span>TESTCASE, TOM</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>MRNumber:</label>
            <span>999999</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>Patient DOB:</label>
            <span>99/99/9999</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <table id="tblhistorian">
        <caption>Historian</caption>
        <tr>
            <th>Time Entered</th>
            <th>Historian</th>
            <th>Historian Name</th>
            <th>Other Persons</th>
            <th>Language</th>
            <th>Other Language</th>
            <th>Translator</th>
            <th>Entered By</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                99/99/9999
            </td>
            <td>
                Mother
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                English
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                Dr. Who
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>



    <ul id="ulPatientAllergies">
        <li>
            <label>Allergies:</label>
            <span>BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <table id="tblTobaccoUse">
        <caption>Tobacco Use</caption>
        <tr>
            <th>Patient Uses Tobacco</th>
            <th>Family Uses Tobacco</th>
            <th>Entered By</th>
            <th>Time Entered</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>N/A</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>Someone</td>
            <td>99/99/9999</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table id="outsidemedications">
        <caption>Active Prescriptions</caption>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Prescribed By</th>
            <th>Prescription</th>
            <th>SIG</th>
            <th>Route</th>
            <th>Dispense</th>
            <th>Refills</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                99/99/9999
            </td>
            <td>
                DR. WHO
            </td>
            <td>
                BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH
            </td>
            <td>
                BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH
            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                0
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                99/99/9999
            </td>
            <td>
                DR. WHO
            </td>
            <td>
                BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH
            </td>
            <td>
                BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH
            </td>
            <td>
                BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH
            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>




    <table id="outsidemedications">
        <caption>Other Medications</caption>
        <tr>
            <th>Medication</th>
            <th>SIG</th>
            <th>Source</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Comments</th>
            <th>Entered By</th>
            <th>Date Entered</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="7">No current medications.</td>
        </tr>
    </table>




    <table id="tblChiefComplaints">
        <caption>Chief Complaints</caption>
        <tr>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Duration</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>General</td>
            <td>BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH</td>
            <td>BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>General</td>
            <td>BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH</td>
            <td>BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table id="tblReviewOfSystems">
        <caption>Review of Systems</caption>
        <tr>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Symptom</th>
            <th>Result</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>General</td>
            <td>BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH</td>
            <td>None</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Skin</td>
            <td>BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH</td>
            <td>None</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Eyes</td>
            <td>BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH</td>
            <td>None</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ears</td>
            <td>BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH</td>
            <td>None</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Nose</td>
            <td>BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH</td>
            <td>None</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mouth or Teeth</td>
            <td>BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH</td>
            <td>None</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Face or Neck</td>
            <td>BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH</td>
            <td>None</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Respiratory</td>
            <td>BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH</td>
            <td>None</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cardio</td>
            <td>BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH</td>
            <td>None</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Abdomen</td>
            <td>BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH </td>
            <td>None</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>MSLymph</td>
            <td>BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH</td>
            <td>None</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Neuro</td>
            <td>BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH</td>
            <td>None</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table id="tblPesentIllnesses">
        <caption>History of Present Illnesses</caption>
        <tr>
            <th>Complaint</th>
            <th>Entered By</th>
            <th>Time Entered</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH</td>
            <td>Dr. Who</td>
            <td>99/99/9999</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH</td>
            <td>Dr. Who</td>
            <td>99/99/9999</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH</td>
            <td>Dr. Who</td>
            <td>99/99/9999</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table id="tblFamilyIllnesses">
        <caption>Family History</caption>
        <tr>
            <th>Relationship</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>DOB</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Illness</th>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table id="tblWellChildHistory">
        <caption>Well Child History</caption>
        <tr>
            <th>Dietary History</th>
            <th>Physical Activity</th>
            <th>Sleeping Habits</th>
            <th>Bowel Habits</th>
            <th>Dental Visit In Past Year</th>
            <th>Exposure To Illnesses</th>
            <th>Alcohol Use</th>
            <th>Drug Use</th>
            <th>Travel History</th>
            <th>Sexual Activity</th>
            <th>Entered By</th>
            <th>Time Entered</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">No past medical history.</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table id="tblSocialHistory">
        <caption>Social History</caption>
        <tr>
            <th>Primary Caregiver</th>
            <th>Home Status</th>
            <th>Child Attends</th>
            <th>School Name</th>
            <th>Grade</th>
            <th>School Performance</th>
            <th>Entered By</th>
            <th>Time Entered</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="12">No social history entered for this visit.</td>
        </tr>
    </table>


    <table id="tblDevelopmentalMilestones">
        <caption>Developmental Milestones</caption>
        <tr>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Question</th>
            <th>Answer</th>
            <th>Entered By</th>
            <th>TimeEntered</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">No developmental assessment entered.</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table id="tblDevelopmentalComments">
        <caption>Developmental Comments</caption>
        <tr>
            <th>Comment</th>
            <th>Entered By</th>
            <th>TimeEntered</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">No developmental comments entered.</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table id="tblHouseholdRiskFactorResponses">
        <caption>Household Risk Factors</caption>
        <tr>
            <th>Question</th>
            <th>Response</th>
            <th>Comment</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">No household risk factors entered for this visit.</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="tblFamilyBarriersResponses">
        <caption>Family Barriers</caption>
        <tr>
            <th>Question</th>
            <th>Response</th>
            <th>Comment</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">No household risk factors entered for this visit.</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table id="tblPHQAAssessments">
        <caption>PHQ-A Assessment</caption>
        <tr>
            <th>Question</th>
            <th>Response</th>
            <th>Score</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">No current assessments.</td>
        </tr>
    </table>


    <table id="tblPatientVitals">
        <caption>Vitals</caption>
        <tr>
            <th>Time Entered</th>
            <th>Temp.</th>
            <th>H.R.</th>
            <th>R.R.</th>
            <th>Weight</th>
            <th>Height</th>
            <th>BMI</th>
            <th>Head Circ.</th>
            <th>O2 Sat.</th>
            <th>BP</th>
            <th>Comments</th>
            <th>Entered By</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>11/3/2017 2:51:00 PM</td>
            <td>98.6</td>
            <td>90</td>
            <td>25</td>
            <td>58.0000</td>
            <td>0.0000</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>0.0000</td>
            <td>0.0000</td>
            <td>0/0&nbsp;Sitting&nbsp;Sitting</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Dr. Who</td>
        </tr>
    </table>


    <ul id="ulexamdetails">
        <li id="liphysicalexamheader">Physical Exam</li>
        <li><span class="categorylabel">General</span></li>
        <li><span class="spnormal">BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH</span><span class="spexception">&nbsp;Except:&nbsp;BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH</span></li>
        <li><span class="categorylabel">Skin</span></li>
        <li><span class="spnormal">BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH</span></li>
        <li><span class="categorylabel">Head</span></li>
        <li><span class="spnormal">BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH</span></li>
        <li><span class="categorylabel">Eyes</span></li>
        <li><span class="spnormal">BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH</span></li>
        <li><span class="categorylabel">Ears</span></li>
        <li><span class="spnormal">BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH</span></li>
        <li><span class="categorylabel">Nose</span></li>
        <li><span class="spnormal">BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH</span></li>
        <li><span class="categorylabel">Mouth</span></li>
        <li><span class="spnormal">BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH</span><span class="spexception">&nbsp;Except:&nbsp;BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH</span></li>
        <li><span class="categorylabel">Face Or Neck</span></li>
        <li><span class="spnormal">BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH</span></li>
        <li><span class="categorylabel">Respiratory</span></li>
        <li><span class="spnormal"></span></li>
        <li><span class="categorylabel">Cardio</span></li>
        <li>
            <span class="spnormal">BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH
            </span>
        </li>
        <li><span class="categorylabel">Abdomen</span></li>
        <li>
            <span class="spnormal">BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH
            </span>
        </li>
        <li><span class="categorylabel">MS/Lymph</span></li>
        <li><span class="spnormal">BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH</span></li>
        <li><span class="categorylabel">Neuro</span></li>
        <li><span class="spnormal">BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH</span></li>

    </ul>

    <table id="tblVisionResults">
        <caption>Vision Results</caption>
        <tr>
            <th>Left Eye</th>
            <th>Right Eye</th>
            <th>Entered By</th>
            <th>Time Entered</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">No vision results this visit.</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="tblHearingTestResults">
        <caption>Hearing Results</caption>
        <tr>
            <th>Frequency</th>
            <th>Db Right</th>
            <th>Db Left</th>
            <!--
            <th>Entered By</th>
            <th>Time Entered</th>
                -->
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">No hearing results this visit.</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="tblInhouseLabs">
        <caption>In-house Labs</caption>
        <tr>
            <th>Lab</th>
            <th>Lab Value</th>
            <th>Comment</th>
            <th>Entered By</th>
            <th>Time Entered</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">No in-house labs results this visit.</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="tblInhouseUrineResults">
        <caption>In-house Urine Results</caption>
        <tr>
            <th>Leukocytes</th>
            <th>Nitrite</th>
            <th>Urobili</th>
            <th>Protein</th>
            <th>PH</th>
            <th>Blood</th>
            <th>SG</th>
            <th>Ketone</th>
            <th>Bilirubin</th>
            <th>Glucose</th>
            <th>Entered By</th>
            <th>Time Entered</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="12">No urine results this visit.</td>
        </tr>
    </table>


    <table id="tblInOfficeCourse">
        <caption>Assessment</caption>
        <tr>
            <th>In-Office Course</th>
            <th>Entered By</th>
            <th>Time Entered</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">No in-office course.</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <fieldset id="fldassessment">
        <legend>Assessment</legend>
        <table id="tbldiagnosiscodes" name="tbldiagnosiscodes"></table>
        <table id="tblPatientAssessment">
            <caption>Assessment</caption>
            <tr>
                <th>Assessment</th>
                <th>Entered By</th>
                <th>Time Entered</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH</td>
                <td>Dr. Who</td>
                <td>99/99/9999</td>

            </tr>
        </table>

        <table id="tblComplianced">
            <caption>Compliance</caption>
            <tr>
                <th>Compliance</th>
                <th>Compliance Code</th>
                <th>Entered By</th>
                <th>Time Entered By</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">No Compliance Entered This Visit.</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="fldplanofcare">
        <legend>Plan of Care</legend>
        <table id="tblvisitprescriptions" name="tblvisitprescriptions"></table>
        <table id="tblDiagnosisCodes">
            <caption>Diagnosis Codes</caption>
            <tr>
                <th>Code</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">No Diagnosis Codes Entered</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <table id="tblCPTCodes">
            <caption>CPT Codes</caption>
            <tr>
                <th>Code</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    99213
                </td>
                <td>
                    ESTAB. EXPANDED
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <table id="tblPrescriptionsThisVisit">
            <caption>Prescriptions This Visit</caption>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Prescribed By</th>
                <th>Prescription</th>
                <th>SIG</th>
                <th>Route</th>
                <th>Dispense</th>
                <th>Refills</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    99/99/9999
                </td>
                <td>
                    Dr. Who
                </td>
                <td>
                    BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH
                </td>
                <td>
                    BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH
                </td>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td>
                    0
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>





        <table id="tblLabsOrdered">
            <caption>Labs Ordered This Visit</caption>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Test Ordered</th>
                <th>Ordered By</th>
                <th>Order Urgency</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">No Labs Ordered This Visit.</td>
            </tr>
        </table>


        <table id="outsidemedications">
            <caption>Radiology Orders This Visit</caption>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Test Ordered</th>
                <th>Ordered By</th>
                <th>Order Urgency</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">No Radiology Ordered This Visit.</td>
            </tr>
        </table>


        <table id="tblcptcodes" name="tblcptcodes"></table>
        <table id="tblReferrals">
            <caption>Referrals This Visit</caption>
            <tr>
                <th>Speciality</th>
                <th>Speciality Group</th>
                <th>Specialist</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">No Referrals This Visit.</td>
            </tr>
        </table>


        <div id="divplanofcare">
            <ul id="ulcareplanlist">
                <li>BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </fieldset>
</div>
<!--End of body-->
<footer class="onlyprint">
    <ul>
        <li>Tom Testcase</li>
        <li>99/99/9999</li>
    </ul>
</footer>
</body>
```

I'm not exactly sure how to implement the CSS to make sure the page contents don't overwrite the footer.  Also, since many of the elements on the page are tables that may expand, do you have to have some advance knowledge of how much data is in these element on where to use page break?  Would someone please help me get started?  Thanks.

Comment: Check out paged media, it will help with your page breaks, headers and footers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Paged_Media

Comment: have you had a look at the samples on the itextpdf.com site?

Comment: Here is a thorough tutorial https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/686994/Create-Read-Advance-PDF-Report-using-iTextSharp-in

Answer (score 1):

An example of setting up your document with headers, footers and page breaks with CSS:

**Page set up**

```
@page {
    size: A4 portrait;
    margin-left: 0.5cm;
    margin-right: 0.5cm;
    background: #FFF;
}
```

**Headers**

```
@page {
    @top-left {
        margin: 10pt 0 10pt 10pt;
        border-top: .25pt solid #666;
        font-size: 9pt;
        color: #FFF;
    }

    @top-center {
        margin: 10pt 10pt 10pt 0;
        border-top: .25pt solid #666;
        font-size: 9pt;
        color: #FFF;
    }

    @top-right {
        margin: 10pt 10pt 10pt 0;
        border-top: .25pt solid #666;
        font-size: 9pt;
        color: #FFF;          
    }
}
```

**Footers**

```
@page {
    @bottom-left {
        margin: 10pt 0 10pt 10pt;
        border-top: .25pt solid #666;
        font-size: 9pt;
        color: #FFF;
    }

    @bottom-center {
        margin: 10pt 10pt 10pt 0;
        border-top: .25pt solid #666;
        font-size: 9pt;
        color: #FFF;
    }

    @bottom-right {
        margin: 10pt 10pt 10pt 0;
        border-top: .25pt solid #666;
        font-size: 9pt;
        color: #FFF;
        content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages); /* Add if you need page numbers */
    }
}
```

**Page breaks**

Use `page-break-before`, `page-break-after`, and `page-break-inside` on your elements to set up appropriate page breaks.

**Additional reading**

1. https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Paged_Media

**Update by Bruno Lowagie**

The above anwer is correct, but incomplete. It explains how to define headers and footers in HTML, but doesn't explain how to create a PDF with those headers and footers. Fortunately, this requires only a single line of code.

See the [HTML to PDF tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml). In [Chapter 2: defining styles and CSS](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-2-defining-styles-css), there's a section named **Adding "Page X of Y" using an @page rule** that shows how the `@page` rule works in combination with the pdfHTML add-on for iText 7.

All you need to do, is write this line of code:

```
HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(src, dest);
```

where `src` is the source (a HTML file) and `dest` is the destination (a PDF file).

Comment: I saw you deleted the answer at the same moment I updated it. I'm happy to see that you undeleted it, because this is indeed a good and easy way to create PDF's with headers and footers (almost no C# code needed, just HTML and CSS).

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance.  Are you suggesting I originally set up the page in HTML and then convert the HTML to PDF?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie yes I thought I was on the wrong track and was going to re-write my answer, though was reaffirmed by your edit - thanks!

Comment: @kmcnet yep - essentially, use HTML for your content, CSS to style the page, and iTextSharp to convert to PDF.

Here is a good tutorial to understand the CSS needed: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/01/designing-for-print-with-css/

Comment: @kmcnet You have two answers with two valid options. It's up to you to decide what's the best option for your project. It could be Matt's where you create HTML and convert to PDF; it could be mine where you program your PDF and use event handlers for headers and footers. We can't make that decision for you because we don't know your project.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I'm really struggling with the HTML portion of this puzzle, especially setting up the headers and footers on each page.  Here is some sample HTML I'm hoping someone can help get me started:

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm trying to implement creating the HTML and then convert to PDF, but I am struggling setting up the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: we no longer talk about iTextSharp. iTextSharp was renamed to iText for .NET. The current version is iText 7.

Adding headers and footers is explained in [chapter 3](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net/chapter-3-using-renderers-and-event-handlers) of the [iText 7 Jump-Start Tutorial for .NET](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net/):

First, you need to create an implementation of the `IEventHandler` interface, for example:

```
protected internal class MyEventHandler : IEventHandler {
    public virtual void HandleEvent(Event @event) {
        PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent)@event;
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = docEvent.GetDocument();
        PdfPage page = docEvent.GetPage();
        int pageNumber = pdfDoc.GetPageNumber(page);
        Rectangle pageSize = page.GetPageSize();
        PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page.NewContentStreamBefore(), page.GetResources(), pdfDoc);
        //Set background
        Color limeColor = new DeviceCmyk(0.208f, 0, 0.584f, 0);
        Color blueColor = new DeviceCmyk(0.445f, 0.0546f, 0, 0.0667f);
        pdfCanvas.SaveState()
                    .SetFillColor(pageNumber % 2 == 1 ? limeColor : blueColor)
                    .Rectangle(pageSize.GetLeft(), pageSize.GetBottom(), pageSize.GetWidth(), pageSize.GetHeight())
                    .Fill()
                    .RestoreState();
        //Add header and footer
        pdfCanvas.BeginText()
                    .SetFontAndSize(C03E03_UFO.helvetica, 9)
                    .MoveText(pageSize.GetWidth() / 2 - 60, pageSize.GetTop() - 20)
                    .ShowText("THE TRUTH IS OUT THERE")
                    .MoveText(60, -pageSize.GetTop() + 30)
                    .ShowText(pageNumber.ToString())
                    .EndText();
        //Add watermark
        iText.Layout.Canvas canvas = new iText.Layout.Canvas(pdfCanvas, pdfDoc, page.GetPageSize());
        canvas.SetProperty(Property.FONT_COLOR, Color.WHITE);
        canvas.SetProperty(Property.FONT_SIZE, 60);
        canvas.SetProperty(Property.FONT, C03E03_UFO.helveticaBold);
        canvas.ShowTextAligned(new Paragraph("CONFIDENTIAL"), 298, 421, pdfDoc.GetPageNumber(page), TextAlignment.
            CENTER, VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE, 45);
        pdfCanvas.Release();
    }
}
```

In the event handler above, we set a back ground, add a header and a footer, add a watermark. That's more than you need, but feel free to adapt.

Once you have this implementation, you can declare it as an event handler for a specific `PdfDocument` instance:

```
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
pdf.AddEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, new MyEventHandler(this));
```

For the full example, see [C03E03_UFO.cs](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/examples/chapter-3#2795-c03e03_ufo.cs).

Comment: Bruno. Thanks for the help and interesting information.  It seems like many of your tutorials go hand in hand with well formed and styled HTML pages.  I'm attempting to mimic page rules like you described in Defining styles with CSS,  I have successfully gottent the header and footer displaying on each page, but the body of each page overwrites the header and footer.  I edited the first post to show the current HTML.  I'm not sure where I'm gong wrong.  Obviously, I can't move on to converting to PDF.

Comment: Imagine a printer that prints on stationery paper. The document nor the printer are aware of what is already printed on that paper, and there's a risk the content of the document will overlap with the preprinted content on the paper. To avoid this, you have to define the margins of the document in such a way that the overlap doesn't happen.

Comment: Bruno.  I appreciate and understand the analogy, but can't seem to get this to work in practice.  I've played with the margins on the @page, but nothing seems to work.  Any insight?